# jQuery Toggle Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When you click open - a div slides out. If you click on the new div, an additional div slides out from under it. This is working great, but I need two things that I cant figure out!

1. How can I condense the jQuery so I don't have to add a class to it every time I want a new slider? Is it possible to do a `.sibling` kind of thing, or something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rs2QK/982/)?
2. I've tried making a close button, but I cannot get it to work the way I want. When you click close, I want the bottom div to close first, then the slide out div to close. And this button would need to work even if only one div is open.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avXSd/67/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.cambridge').hide();  
   $("#test").click(function () {
      $(".cambridge").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
   });
   $('.shopping').hide();  
   $("#test2").click(function () {
      $(".shopping").toggle("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
   });
});
```

Comment: I figured out the second part! 

Now if you hit the close button, the bottom slider closes first, then the main slider closes second. 
 http://jsfiddle.net/avXSd/78/

I still think there is a way to condense this function so that I don't have to edit it every time I want to add a new div. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand your first question. What Css Class are you talking about? i don't see you're adding any class. 

Regarding the second question, you can use the complete callback function on the toggle fn.

`// That's the second question
    $('#showmap').click(function() {
     $(".shopping").toggle("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000, function () {
       $(".cambridge").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
      });
    });`

Answer (score 1):

A quick review:

**JSHint.com**

- Your code passes all checks, well done

**Naming**

- `test` and `test2` are unfortunate names for elements, I am sure you can come up with something better

**Counter Proposal**

Looking at the code, there is definitely repetition in making those sliders, you can extract what is common in to a function, and then use that function for any future sliders:

(This is blatantly stolen/modified from the deleted answer):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   function registerSlider( buttonId, sliderClass, direction){
     $(sliderClass).hide();  
     $(buttonId).click(function () {
       $(sliderClass).toggle("slide", { direction: direction }, 1000);
     });
   }   
   registerSlider("#test", '.cambridge', 'right' );
   registerSlider("#test2", '.shopping', 'up' );

});
```

**Your questions**

1. I showed in my counter proposal how you can condense the code, but I do believe you will need each time a distinct class
2. Finding the answer to that question is not trivial (we would need a working sample), and not something codereview does.

Comment: Haha, your answer tricked me into answering a 4 year old question as well. Well done. :D

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you another way, how you can handle this. This solution will work with any number of slides. I hope this helps you. The basic idea is this:

- open a slide
- save this slide on a stack
- continue opening slides *or*
- close one or more slides

In case of closing it will close all slides up to the selected one. This way you don't need a *close all* button and you can't get a result where a "*nested*" slide is still open but its parent is closed.

**HTML**

To loosen the JavaScript from the markup I've introduced some `data-*`-attributes:

- `data-slide="[name]"`
- `data-id="[name]"`
- `data-direction="[right|up]"`

*data-slide="[name]"* represents a trigger for a slide. In your case:

```
<div data-slide="slide-1">Toggle Slider</div>
```

*data-id="[name]"* identifies a slide. Also information about the direction is stored here:

```
<div class="cambridge slideout" data-id="slide-1" data-direction="right">
```

**JavaScript**

```
const DELAY = 1000;
var stack = [];

function close(e) {
    var value = null;

    if (!stack.length) {
        return;
    }

    value = stack.pop();
    value.removeClass('active').toggle('slide', {direction: value.data('direction')}, DELAY);

    if (!e.length || e.data('id') != value.data('id')) {
        setTimeout(function() { close(e); }, DELAY);
    }
}

$('[data-slide]').click(function() {
    var e = $('[data-id="' + $(this).data('slide') + '"]');

    if (!e.hasClass('active')) {
        e.addClass('active').toggle('slide', {direction: e.data('direction')}, DELAY);
        stack.push(e);
    } else {
        close(e);
    }
});
```

**Advantages**

- HTML and JavaScript are more decoupled
- no class- or id-selectors necessary
- no *close all* function necessary (but you can simply call `close()` to close all slides anyway)
- no ghost slides are visible if you close a "parent" element

**Further Improvements**

This code can have side effects, when you open a slide while it's closing multiple others. This should be addressed.

**jsFiddle Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/1z5bjeve/)

Comment: Very nice answer ;) +1